# How can I add a custom style to an v-dialog in vuetify after the latest update?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I'm working with vuetify and I need to add a custom class to an v-dialog. I've already search information about it, but my problem is that the prop **"content-class" has been removed from vuetify**. What can I do then? Is there another way?

```
<v-dialog v-model="loginUserDialog" content-class="loginmodalbox" max-width="600px" persistent>
</v-dialog>

.loginmodalbox .modal-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.08);
    padding-bottom: 8px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prop [content-class](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/#props) is still available:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.loginmodalbox .v-card__title {
  background: red!important;
  color: white!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.5.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.5.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500" content-class="loginmodalbox">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
            color="red lighten-2"
            dark
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
          >
            Click Me
          </v-btn>
        </template>

        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            Privacy Policy
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </v-card-text>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialog = false">
              I accept
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```